# How to trigger input image from img tag in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have the following situation:

```
<input type="file" name="profilePicture" id="profilePicture" accept="image/*" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" style="display:none"/>
<img *ngIf="!this.profile.profilePic" src="...a static path..." />
<img *ngIf="this.profile.profilePic" [src]="this.profile.profilePic" />
```

and I would like to trigger the input file on one of the two images that are displayed in the `img` tags, according with the `ngIf`. This means that I want the upload window to open when I click on the image without having the standard input of type "file" as usual. My code, as I wrote it here, doesn't work. Can anybody explain me how to trigger the upload file from the image tag and hide the input tag instead?

**EDIT**

The `onFileSelected` is only a function that processes the uploaded image and store the object in a temporary variable called `profilePicture`:

```
onFileSelected(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
     this.profilePicture = event.target.files[0];
   } else {
    this.profilePicture = undefined;
  }
}
```

`profile` is instead an object which contains all the info related to the user.

**EDIT II**

I tested the code by using only one img tag.
The following code doesn't work either:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" style="display:none"/>
<img [src]="'...the static path...'"/>
```

**EDIT III**

My problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530081/upload-img-by-clicking-on-image-not-input-type-file-display-it-in-follow) that address the same problem I have (and didn't help unfortunately).

Comment: can you upload the code of component

Comment: I suggest to explain the user case. I got confuse.

Comment: Look at my edit and at the question I have linked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) class to read the content of file. The `fileReader.result` is only available when operation is complete.

Add the following to your TS:

```
imageSource;

onFileSelected(e: Event): void {
  if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
    const imageFile = e.target.files[0];

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      return this.imageSource = fileReader.result;
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
  }
}
```

And bind the `imageSource` to your `img` tags:

```
<img [src]="imageSource || 'static path'" alt="My Profile Image"/>
```

You only need to add one `img` tag and works for both cases, if image available or pick it from the path defined.

Comment: The problem is not to read the content of the file. The problem is to trigger the upload by clicking on the image that is currently displayed. I'm testing the code with only one img tag as you suggested.

Comment: No, I want the upload window to open when I click on the image. If I use a separate input field with type="file" everything works perfectly, but I want the input window that allows you to pick up a file to open when I click on the image in the HTML.